# Compilation error in assembly - emu8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm very new to assembly and emu8086 and can't seem to figure out why this line gives out an error:

```
mov [ax], dl
```

while this line works:

```
mov [di], ch
```

The error is: "MOV [ax], dl, probably it's an undefined var: [ax]"

Thanks

Comment: `[ax]` is not a valid effective address. Use `[bx]`, `[bp]`, `[si]` or `[di]`.

Comment: It's a limitation of 8086-architecture: See [8086 Instruction Format & 
Addressing Modes, Page 13](https://dca13d00a675f255e4d75145ccca85da6f5067de.googledrive.com/host/0B3G21MbFQqR7RUxWTWs5a0JJelk/cse/4/Microprocessors%20&%20Microcontrollers/3.8086Addressnew.pdf) `3. For indirect addressing, the 8086 can only use the BX, BP, SI and DI registers.`
]